# Is an $n \times n$ matrix with rank $n$ always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank

I have an assignment problem:

> Which statement(s) about an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is/are always true?
>
> 1. If the rank of $A$ is $n$, then $A$ is diagonalizable.
> 2. If $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizable.
> 3. If one or more of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $0$, then $A$ cannot be diagonalized.

I know that $\#2$ is true, because if it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then it is diagonalizable.

I know that $\#3$ is false, for example the matrix of all zeroes is diagonalizable (since it's already diagonal) and has zero eigenvalues, so $\#3$ is clearly false.

---

I am not sure about $\#1$. I know that rank $n$ means that the columns are all linearly independent. I think it means that it is diagonalizable but I am not certain.

Thanks for help.

Comment: No, take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: ^ Always keep that matrix in your back pocket, along with the identity matrix and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid :(

Comment: Btw, in case it's not clear, the reason $\displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable is because its eigenvalues are both $1$, hence it would have to be similar to the identity matrix $I$. But the only matrix similar to $I$ is itself, because $SIS^{-1} = I$ for any invertible $S$. For the same reason, any triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are all the same, is not diagonalizable unless it is already diagonal.